# Implementing Closures and Self invocation of functions

Tags: javascript

In this, I am trying to assign the start time in the beginning and when I will click on the page it should return me the time spent but I am getting  0 always. I am not understanding that where I might have gone. Need your help.

```
     var timeSpent = (function(){
        var time    = new Date();
        var timeRun = false,
            startTime = time.getTime();

        return function(){ // call this function by timeSpent()(); 
            return time.getTime() - startTime;
        }
    })();

    addEventListener("click", function(){
        console.log(timeSpent());
    })
```

Comment: `time` and `startTime` are the same time. The instances of Date aren't live, they contain the time which was current at the time the instances were created.

Comment: In this I want that startTime get its value assigned at the time of start of page and when the function runs again then I get the difference between the time when user entered the page and clicks on the page.

Comment: @PraveenKumarRana — Then you need to replace `time.getTime()` (which is when the user entered the page) with the current time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate the present time inside the inner function

```js
var timeSpent = (function(){
    var time    = new Date();
    var timeRun = false,
        startTime = time.getTime();

    return function(){ // call this function by timeSpent()(); 
        return (new Date()).getTime() - startTime;
    }
})();

addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log(timeSpent());
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`time` is a date. Every time you call `getTime()` on it, you will get the same value.

So `startTime` and `time.getTime()` will always be the same.

You need to replace `time.getTime()` **inside the returned function** with something which will get the **current** time. `(new Date()).getTime()`

```js
var timeSpent = (function() {
  var time = new Date();
  var timeRun = false,
    startTime = time.getTime();

  return function() { // call this function by timeSpent()(); 
    return (new Date()).getTime() - startTime;
  }
})();

addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log(timeSpent());
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function `timeSpent()` is evaluated as (you can check it by logging the function in console)

`return time.getTime() - startTime;`

As, `startTime = time.getTime()` initially. Therefore, the above `return` statement will evaluted to 0. In order to get the current time, you will have to
call `new Date().getTime()`

```js
var timeSpent = (function(){
    var time    = new Date();
    var timeRun = false,
        startTime = time.getTime();

    return function(){ // call this function by timeSpent()(); 
        return new Date().getTime() - startTime;
    }
})();

addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log(timeSpent());
})
```